# Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]" from another module or realm when using npm link

Tags: npm, graphql, graphql-js, npm-link

I'm using `npm link` to change my private package and see changes in action in another project. The problem is that both my projects use `graphql` as a dependency so I get an error `Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]"` I was trying to use `resolutions` key in package.json of my main project. Unfortunately it didn't help. So, I'm clueless about how to resolve this issue without pushing a newer version of my package to npm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get around this do the following

1. `npm i -g graphql`
2. For each dependant project, inside the working directory

   1. `npm link graphql`

This will connect to the globally installed graphql for each project and allow you to share the module without the shared directory structure

Comment: You can also npm link the copy of graphql from your private package (rather than installing globally): in the private package `cd node_modules/graphql; npm link` then in dependent projects `npm link graphql`.